# Why is "lousy" pronounced like "louzy"?

Tags: pronunciation, pejorative-language

As "lousy" is a pejorative for someone or something being infested with lice, why is it pronounced with a "z" instead of an "s" sound?

OTOH, when a person is called a "louse," the "s" sound *is* used.

Doubtless most people who use the word (lousy) don't really know what they're saying, thus the mispronunciation, but how did it get started in the first place?

Comment: Have you done any research at all?  Both [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/lousy) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lousy) stipulate that the "z" sound is the proper pronunciation, and not a mispronunciation.

Comment: I'm not sure your meaning of lousy concurs with [normal use](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lousy). Where did you get this definition from? If you were infested with lice you would be [*lice-infested*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lice-infested) - link might not work everywhere. As a native BrE speaker, if I wanted to express something being louse-like I would probably say *lous-ey* pronouncing it the same as *mousey* or [licey](https://www.yourdictionary.com/licey).

Comment: +1 for your **comment** @user067531

Comment: It's because of the louzy English language!  What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 4):

As to why that sort of change happens in general: the /s/ in *louse* becomes intervocalic (it is now between vowels) in *lousy* and thus becomes *more likely* to trigger lenition. It adjusts to the sounds preceding and following it, which are both more sonorous and becomes voiced too. I think it's supposed to make the pronunciation slightly easier and is a common change observed in multiple languages.

For a historical perspective on this particular word, user067531's comment seems to be spot-on.

Comment: In the word _lousy_ /'lawzi/, all segments are voiced. If it were pronounced with /s/ instead of /z/, voicing would have to be turned off and then on again in the middle of the word. This is possible, but it costs effort that is unnecessary (hardly anyone notices and nobody at all cares whether it's voiced or not), so it's usually simply ignored, until it becomes a habit, then a convention.

Comment: it's done all the time in other languages (ex: Spanish), so maybe English speakers are lazy @JohnLawler

Comment: @green_ideas so is lenition (e.g. Spanish)

Comment: Every language has its own pattern of sound formations and lenitions. Of course English speakers are lazy; so are all speakers. The principle of minimum effort is a constant in human behavior.